# WriteStream to String and then writeFile

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a ReadStream.
When I pipe to a WriteStream on a file, it perfectly writes the file.

```
x.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.zip'))
```

But the problem appends because the lib I use doesn't accept readStream but only "string". I do so:

```
const chunks = []
x.data.on('data', chunk => {
    chunks.push(chunk)
})
x.data.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err)
})
x.data.on('end', () => {
    fs.writeFile('test.zip', Buffer.concact(chunks).toString())
})
```

Doesn't work... Do you know why ?